# Using GROUP_CONCAT with FIND_IN_SET in mysql WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query and want get appointment data from the table using student email but it get this error `Unknown column 'stu' in 'where clause'`

```
select a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(e.value) as stu FROM wp_ea_appointments a join
wp_ea_fields e on a.id = e.app_id WHERE a.date > DATE('2019-02-14') AND
FIND_IN_SET('jan@gmail.com' , stu ) GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET` condition should be contained in `HAVING` statement instead of `WHERE` statement because you want to filter data after grouping

```
SELECT a.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(e.value) as stu 
FROM wp_ea_appointments a 
JOIN wp_ea_fields e ON a.id = e.app_id 
WHERE a.date > DATE('2019-02-14')
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('jan@gmail.com', stu)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using subquery

```
select * from
(
select a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(e.value) as stu FROM wp_ea_appointments a join
wp_ea_fields e on a.id = e.app_id WHERE a.date > DATE('2019-02-14') 
GROUP BY a.id
)A where FIND_IN_SET('jan@gmail.com' , stu )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HAVING` clause, but phrase the logic correctly:

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(e.value) as stu
FROM wp_ea_appointments a JOIN
     wp_ea_fields e 
     ON a.id = e.app_id
WHERE a.date > DATE('2019-02-14')
HAVING SUM( e.value = 'jan@gmail.com' ) > 0;
```

There is no reason to use string concatenation to check whether the value exists.  The string comparisons are more expensive and less clear.